# Scope of malloc used in a function

Tags: c, malloc

When a function returns, is the memory allocated via malloc freed? Or can it still be accessed in the main() function using pointers?

eg.

```
void function(int *a)
{
    a=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *a=10;
}
int main()
{
    int *num;
    function(num);
    printf("%d",*num);
    return(0);
}
```

Can the integer stored in a be accessed by main() here?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No, the memory allocated with malloc is not freed when you leave the scope/return from the function.

You're responsible for freeing the memory you malloc.

In your case though, the memory is NOT accesible in main(), but that's because you only deal with a local variable.

```
void function(int *a)
{
    a=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Here, `a` is a local variable within `function` . Pointers are passed by value in C, so `a` receives a copy of the pointer in main when you do `function(num);` main() does not see that you assign to that local copy of the pointer.

You have to do either:

```
void function(int **a)
{
  *a= malloc(sizeof(int));
  **a=10;
}
int main()
{
  int *num;
  function(&num);
  printf("%d",*num);
  free(num);
  return(0);
}
```

or

```
int* function(void)
{
  int *a= malloc(sizeof(int));
  *a=10;
  return a;
}
int main()
{
  int *num;
  num = function();
  printf("%d",*num);
  free(num);
  return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`malloc()`ed memory is only freed when you call `free()` on it. It can be accessed by anybody with a valid pointer to it until that time.

Answer (score 3):

No. You are passing the pointer `num`by value, hence the changes made by the `function` will not be reflected in `main`. So effectively there is no way to access/free the allocated memory from `main`

To fix this you can pass the address of `num`  or return `a` from function and collect the returned value in `num`

Answer (score 1):

Memory is not freed. Any function can allocate memory and any other can deallocate it. It's a real mess if you're not super-finicky, until... someone invented the Garbage Collection.

Answer (score 1):

malloc is working fine (though you will have to call free() on the pointer it returns). The problem here is that you aren't returning a pointer to the memory it allocated.

"int * a", your parameter to function() is the address of an integer. The usual way to return that would be to rewrite your function as follows:

```
int * function()
{
  int * a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
  *a = 10;
  return a;
}
```

To return it via a parameter, you need to return the address of the pointer:

```
//  pp points to a pointer
void function( int ** pp )
{
    //  Assign allocated memory to the thing that pp points to
    *pp = (int *)malloc( sizeof( int ) );

    //  Get the thing pp points to -- a pointer.
    //  Then get the thing which THAT pointer points to -- an integer
    //  Assign 10 to that integer. 
    **pp = 10;
}

void main()
{
    int * p = NULL;

    function( & p );

    printf( "%d\n", *p );

    free( p );
}
```

And now you know why they invented C#.

Here's a way to rewrite your allocation thing so it's more clear:

```
void function( int ** pp )
{
    int * newmemory = (int *)malloc( sizeof( int ) );

    //  Assign 10 to the integer-sized piece of memory we just allocated. 
    *newmemory = 10;

    //  Assign allocated memory to the thing that pp points to. 
    *pp = newmemory;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the direct address of the allocated memory in a list container then create a function to loop, access each address into a free function, and then pop out the address.  You can insert the address directly into the free function like `free(myaddresslist.front()); myaddresslist.pop_front();` .  This is a quasi way of doing your own garbage collection without having to change your entire project to GC based languages.  Use `myaddresslist.size()` to make sure you don't call free() on an empty field (resulting in a crash) and to determine the number of loops to take.