# Is this a valid example of call by reference not being true in C?

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

```
#include <stdio.h>


void changePtr(int* ptr) {

printf("Value of ptr is %d, address is %d \n" , *ptr,&ptr);
int b = 50;
ptr = &b;
printf("Value of ptr in function changePtr is %d, address is %d  \n", *ptr , &ptr);

}


int main() {

int a = 10;
int* ptr;
ptr = &a;
changePtr(ptr);
printf("Value of ptr in main is %d, address is %d  \n", *ptr,&ptr);
return 0;
}
```

This is the output

```
Value of ptr is 10, address is 13368768
Value of ptr in function changePtr is 50, address is 13368768
Value of ptr in main is 10, address is 13368980
```

Over here, when I call function changePtr with ptr as it's argument, the function changePtr doesn't receive the pointer itself, rather the value of ptr in main(), and the variable ptr in the function changePtr is a totally new pointer that copies the value from the pointer ptr received from main().

If C supports call by reference, the output at the lower two lines would match.

Comment: C doesn't have references.

Comment: If you want to use [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to print a pointer, you should use the `"%p"` format to print a `void*` (casting is necessary).

Answer (score 2):

> *If C supports call by reference,.....*

C has no concept of pass by reference for function argument passing. Arguments are always passed using pass by value.

We can achieve the similar behavior of *pass by reference* through passing a pointer to the *object* and manipulating the value at address pointed by the pointer from inside the called function, but then, **the pointer itself is passed by value.**

That implies, if you have to change a *pointer* itself from the called function, you should be sending a pointer to the pointer variable to achieve that. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3629118/2173917) for a nice code-wise example.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a pointer. This pointer is passed *by value*. I.e. the pointer itself is copied for the function. So when you make `ptr` inside the function point somewhere else, you are only changing the local copy of the pointer.

If you want to change the value of where the pointer is pointing, you need to use the dereference operator `*`:

```
void changePtr(int* ptr) {
    *ptr = 50;
}
```

This will *emulate* pass by reference.

---

If you instead pass a pointer to the pointer variable (emulating passing the pointer by reference), like the following (simplified version of your) program

```
void changePtr(int** ptr) {
    int b = 50;
    *ptr = &b;
}

int main() {
    int a = 10;
    int* ptr = &a;
    changePtr(&ptr);
    printf("Value of ptr in main is %d, address is %p\n",*ptr, (void *) &ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

That is actually *worse* because after the `changePtr` call the pointer is pointing to a local variable inside the `changePtr` function, a variable which have gone out of scope and no longer exists. This leads to *undefined behavior* when using the pointer.

Comment: For the sake of this example (pointer-to-pointer ~= pointer-by-reference) you could make it `static int b = 50;` to get rid of the UB.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. What you do is to pass the pointer (address of a) by value. When you call the function a new pointer will be created containing the value of the old pointer ptr. This value is the address of a. When you change the functions ptr the main ptr will not changed because they where not the same. They just pointed to the same element.

Answer (score 0):

The identifier `ptr` by alone is a pointer and is not meaningful unless you tell it what type it should point to ie

```
int *ptr;  //says  int <- *ptr or *ptr is an integer
```

In

```
changePtr(ptr); // You pass pointer by value
```

and in

```
void changePtr(int* ptr) 
/* you caught the argument 'ptr' from main
 * using the function parameter 'ptr'
 */
```

so

`ptr_from_main` & `ptr_from_funtion` contians the same value at this point that is `13368980` as obtained from your example.

You have a mistake in the `printf` statement that follows, not using the format specifier `%p` for printing the address, it should have been

```
printf("Value of ptr is %d, address is %p \n" , *ptr,&ptr);
```

Also you should have used `ptr` instead of `&ptr` for the example to be more meaningful,ie

```
printf("Value of ptr is %d, address is %p \n" , *ptr,ptr);
/* Would give you
 * Value of ptr is 10, address is 13368980
 */
```

Every pointer is indeed an object which indeed has an an address, so `&ptr` gives you the address of the pointer not its value(remember value is an address indeed :))

---

To emulate call by reference in C++, you need to completely rewrite your program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void changePtr(int** ptr) // Here pointer<-*ptr  & integer<-**ptr;
{
printf("Value of ptr is %d, address is %p \n" , **ptr,*ptr);
int b = 50;
*ptr = &b; // You've just changed the value of ptr in main
printf("Value of ptr in function changePtr is %d, address is %p  \n", **ptr , *ptr);

}


int main() {

int a = 10;
int* ptr;
ptr = &a;
changePtr(&ptr); // Pass the address
printf("Value of ptr in main is %d, address is %p  \n", *ptr,ptr);
return 0;
}
```